# MediaWiki Infobox_person template

Tags: mediawiki

I've set up a Mediawiki install on our intranet and we wanted to use [Template:Infobox_person](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aInfobox_person). Easy enough, I thought.

I went to [Special:Export](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aExport) and exported the template. I also copied over the Common.css file and enabled ParserFunctions. When I include the Infobox on one of our pages now, I see this at the top:

> {{#invoke:InfoboxImage|InfoboxImage|image=|size=|sizedefault=frameless|alt=|suppressplaceholder=yes}}

I feel like just editing it out of the template is the wrong thing to do, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia uses [the Scribunto extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aScribunto) now to embed [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) logic into templates; the code you copied invokes some code from [Module:InfoboxImage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module%3aInfoboxImage).